# How to display many SVGs in Java with high performance

Tags: java, performance, opengl, svg, java-2d

#### What I want

My goal is to be able to display a large number of SVG images on a single drawing area in Java, each with its own translation/rotation/scale values. I'm looking for the simplest solution allowing this, optionally even using OpenGL to speed things up.

#### What I've Tried

My initial naive approach was to use SVGSalamander to draw directly on a JPanel, but the performance was pathetic.

I poked around around and learned that I should do something like manually convert each SVG into a BufferedImage created with createCompatibleImage, then do the transformations I want, then draw it using double buffering. I ran into some troubles here, and before I continued I tried looking for frameworks to simplify things.

#### What I've Looked At

I've been a bit overwhelmed by the available options, which is why I'm turning to SO for help. I've looked at:

- [Cairo](http://cairographics.org/) (with [Glitz](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/glitz) maybe?)
- [Libart](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/glitz) - not sure if this actually supports SVGs
- [FengGUI](http://www.fenggui.org/doku.php)
- [Slick](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/static.php?page=about) - looks promising but a bit of an overkill

But couldn't decide what is best for me to start working with, and I hope someone here as experience with any of these doing similar things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Render your SVGs to textures, then render textured quads with desired transforms.

Comment: You means I should directly render with OpenGL, then? Not use any of these libraries?